# jquery sortable alert this list id

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-sortable

Really need help

i am using jquery sortable.

And i am looking to grab just the id from the list element that is being dragged.

"Not all off them"

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/isimpledesign/85LdV/1/

this alerts back an array but i need it to give me back just the id of the element that is being dragged so i can pass it to a php file.

Can someone please help me with this????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to clarify Chad's answer a bit -

```
$(function() {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        update: function(event, ui) {
            // i need to get the class text that is being dragged i.e
            var order = $(this).sortable("serialize");
            alert(order); 
            /*
             No need to bind any other events, ui.item is the dragged
             item in 'update' too and we only want to capture the id when the sort
             has changed presumably
            */
            alert(ui.item.attr('id'));
            /*
             No need for subscripting, ui.item is a jquery object so 
             we can just call attr() on it to get the ID
            */
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 Wow, I didn't even bother to check the update event's ui parameter, that was foolish of me. Good call.

Comment: No worries, it's still early in the day :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `start` event:

```
$(function() {
   $("#sortable").sortable({
      update: function(event, ui) {
         // i need to get the class text that is being dragged i.e
        var order = $(this).sortable("serialize");
        alert(order);   
      },
      //Start event fires on the start of a sort
      //you can store the id from in here
      start: function(event, ui) {
         //here ui.item contains a jquery object that is the item being dragged
         alert(ui.item[0].id);
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: @Luccas honestly I'm not sure what you mean, they are different events that fire at different times, with different information passed. [jQuery.sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$(function() {
    var lastMoved = null;
    $("#sortable li").mousedown(function(){
        lastMoved = this;
    });
    $("#sortable").sortable({
      update: function(event, ui) {
        alert($(lastMoved).attr("id"));
      }
    });
});
```

It's tested and working.
Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: This is unreliable as it doesn't rely on sorting at all anymore. You would return the ID anytime an object was clicked at all even if the sort doesn't change.

Comment: @HurnsMobile. No you're wrong. It shows the value in the `update` method, that happens only when you changed order. Please analyze it and reconsider your downvote.